# How to add force to an object after a collision in unity2d, to simulate hitting a baseball with a bat

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a 2D game project. I would like the user to be able to hit the ball when he presses on the "space" key. I assigned;

- Circle collider 2D & Rigidbody 2D to the ball
- Rigidbody 2D & Box Collider 2D to the hero
- Edge Collider 2D to the baseball bat.

Here is my script which I have called "KickTheBall.cs":

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;
 public class KickTheBall : MonoBehaviour {
     public float bounceFactor = 0.9f; // Determines how the ball will be bouncing after landing. The value is [0..1]
     public float forceFactor = 10f;
     public float tMax = 5f; // Pressing time upper limit
     private float kickStart; // Keeps time, when you press button
     private float kickForce; // Keeps time interval between button press and release 
     private Vector2 prevVelocity; // Keeps rigidbody velocity, calculated in FixedUpdate()
     [SerializeField]
     private EdgeCollider2D BatCollider;
     private Rigidbody2D rb;
     void Start () {
         rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
     }
     void FixedUpdate () {
         if(kickForce != 0)
         {
             float angle = Random.Range(0,20) * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
             rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0.0f, 
                 forceFactor * Mathf.Clamp(kickForce, 0.0f, tMax) * Mathf.Sin(angle)), 
                 ForceMode2D.Impulse); 
             kickForce = 0;
         }
         prevVelocity = rb.velocity;
     }
     void Update(){
         if(Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space))
         {
             kickStart = Time.time;
             Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
             RaycastHit hit;
             if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
             {
                 if(hit.collider.name == "Ball") // Rename ball object to "Ball" in Inspector, or change name here
                     kickForce = Time.time - kickStart;
             }
         }
     }

     public void KickBall(){
         BatCollider.enabled = true;
     }
     void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
     {
         if(col.gameObject.tag == "Ground") // Do not forget assign tag to the field
         {
             rb.velocity = new Vector2(prevVelocity.x, 
                 -prevVelocity.y * Mathf.Clamp01(bounceFactor));
         }
     }
 }
```

However, I am unable to kick the ball when I press the space key. The ball is just bouncing because of colliders. What am I missing?

Check my result:

[image: .gif image]

Comment: What exactly is not working? You said you are unable to kick the ball, so what happens instead? Also the gif you linked has nothing to do with kicking balls so I guess it is the wrong one?

Comment: The ball is just bouncing because of colliders. @TylerSigi

Comment: Instead of doing it the way you are now. Why don't you just add a oncollisionenter script to the bat/leg, and move the stuff about adding force to the ball to the inside of the oncollision enter targeting col.gameobject.

Comment: "kickForce" Will always be zero. Have you tried to put a breakpoint in your code and debug it?

Comment: Well if the player mouses over the ball it would add force right? It just wouldn't have anything to do with the bat.

Comment: What happens when you press space and mouse over the ball?

Comment: Dear friends, please accept my apologies. I am in the beginner level of Unity and C#. When I mouseover the ball, nothing happens @TylerSigi. Actually, I cannot arrange the related code according to the keyboard: Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advocate something more like this to start with. This is the script you would add onto your baseball bat.

Part 1:

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;
 public class KickTheBall : MonoBehaviour 
 {
     public float forceFactor = 10f;
     private float kickForce = 50f; 

     void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
     {
         if(col.gameObject.tag == "Ball") // Do not forget assign tag to the field
         {
             rb = col.gameobject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();    
             rb.AddForce(transform.right * kickForce);
         }
     }
 }
```

I have simplified your AddForce function for demonstration purposes. Feel free to replace it with your more complex AddForce function if everything is working.

Part 2:

If you really want to include the part where holding the space button makes the hit stronger, then add this:

```
 void Update()
 {
     if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
     {
         kickForce += 0.5f;
     }
 }
```

and add at the end of the oncollisionenter

```
   kickForce = 0;
```

What this will do is build up force while you hold the space button down. After a successful hit the force will reset to 0. So subsequent collisions will not result in a hit until the space button is held again.

Let me know if this did anything for you.

Comment: Thank you very much. My previous script was too complex. You guided me to resolve the problem. @TylerSigi.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue with the help of @TylerSigi. I updated my script file with these codes:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class KickTheBall : MonoBehaviour {
    public float forceFactor = 10f;
    private float kickForce = 0f; 
    private EdgeCollider2D BatCollider;
    public GameObject Ball;

    void Start () {

    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Space)) {
            kickForce = 1000;
        } else {
            kickForce = 0;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if(col.gameObject.tag == "Enemy") // Do not forget assign tag to the field
        {
            Ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(transform.right * kickForce);
        }
    }

}
```